# Mongoose text index: failed to use text index to satisfy $text query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Prior to upgrading my app's packages and dependencies, our text query operations were working fine, but now I'm getting the following error:

> planner returned error :: caused by :: failed to use text index to
> satisfy $text query (if text index is compound, are equality
> predicates given for all prefix fields?)

I saw this in the Mongo docs:

> If the compound text index includes keys preceding the text index key,
> to perform a $text search, the query predicate must include equality
> match conditions on the preceding keys.

However, the index in question only has text keys, so I don't see how this applies. From our Recipe model in mongoose:

```
RecipeBaseSchema.index({ name: 'text', 'tags.primaryIngredient': 'text' });
RecipeUserSchema.index({ name: 'text', 'tags.primaryIngredient': 'text' });
RecipeAdminSchema.index({ name: 'text', 'tags.primaryIngredient': 'text' });
RecipeAdminSchema.index(
  { placeholderDefault: 1 },
  { unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { placeholderDefault: true } },
);
```

From the search handler:

```
const search = async (model, req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const populate = JSON.parse(req.query.populate || {});
    
    const query = {
      $text: { $search: req.params.search },
    };

    const recipes = await model
      .find(query, { score: { $meta: 'textScore' } })
      .where('isDeleted').ne(true)
      .sort({ score: { $meta: 'textScore' } })
      .limit(parseInt(req.query.limit, 10) || 100)
      .skip(parseInt(req.query.skip, 10) || 0)
      .populate(populate);

    return res.status(200).json(recipes);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return next({
      status: 400,
      message: 'Recipes not found',
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Use the MongoDB shell or a GUI tool like Compass to inspect the indexes directly and ensure they match what you expect:

db.recipes.getIndexes()

Comment: I'm getting an empty array when I do this, not sure why